# Java - Break execution sequence using CompletableFuture chain

Tags: java

I am new to Java and am using CompletableFutures to perform async operations such as below:

```java
public CompletionStage<Either<ErrorResponse, Response>> insertOrUpdate(String actor, String key) {
    return this.objectDAO.getByKey(key)
            .thenApply(mapDOToContainer(key))
            .thenApply(mergeContainerToDO(key, actor))
            .thenComposeAsync(this.objectDAO.UpdateFn())
            .thenApply(DBResult::finished)
            .thenApply(finished -> {
                if (finished) {
                    Response response = Response.ok().build();
                    return Either.right(response);
                } else {
                    return Either.left(ErrorResponse.create("Error", 400));
                }
            });
}
```

Now I need to modify this so that if the get fails then I perform the above chain, but if it succeeds then I need to break this chain and return from the function with an Either object containing an ErrorResponse.

How can I break this processing chain? I know I can pass a flag to each function in the chain and achieve this by performing the actions in the functions based on the value of the flag. I was hoping there is a better way to do this.

Thanks!!

Comment: An exception will break the chain.  CompletableFuture's have special methods to deal with the exceptional case,  I wouldn't use `Either` at all to return errors, it is for langauges that don't have exceptions.

Comment: You could apply an [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) like `Optional.of(objectDAO.getByKey(key))`. Or the DAO's method could return an optional, because obviously there's an option that this DAO does not find the key. The point is: [ifPresent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) comes in handy here.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite your code.

- Don't use Either for errors, Java has exception
- Don't return a CompletionStage from your DAO
- Use `exceptionally` from CompletableFuture, it is designed for this

Then do this:

```
public CompletionStage<Response> insertOrUpdate(String actor, String key) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> this.objectDAO.getByKey(key))
            .thenApply(mapDOToContainer(key))
            .thenApply(mergeContainerToDO(key, actor))
            .thenComposeAsync(this.objectDAO.UpdateFn())
            .thenApply(DBResult::finished)
            .thenApply(finished -> {
                Response response = Response.ok().build();
                return response;
            })
            .exceptionally(e -> ErrorResponse.create("Error", 400));
}
```

The DAO should be something like this:

```
class ObjectDAO {
    public Object getByKey(String key) {
        if (keyNotFound) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

        return new Object();
    }
}
```

You may have to make sure that ErrorResponse is a subclass of Response to make this work.

Comment: Thanks! I was a little confused about the use of exceptionally but this clears it.